# image is not showing on image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code is working fine when i load images statistically and when i'm trying to load images dynamically from database, it's throwing error. The error says `nil is not a valid asset source`. Could you please tell me, where i have gone wrong?

Code snippet:

**index.html.erb (books controller)**

```
- <div id="books-index">

     <% @books.each_slice(4) do |book| %>
        <div class="row">
            <% book.each do |book| %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
               <h3>book.title</h3>
                <%= image_tag(book.coverpath) %>
                <%= link_to 'Read more', book_path(book), class:"btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: your `book.coverpath` contains `nil` value instead of image url

Comment: share the output of `book.coverpath`

Comment: coverpath shows image of book.i have images in assets/images folder.

Comment: How to load image ?

Comment: `<%= image_tag('url-of-image-path-or-assets-path') %>`

Comment: Your `book.coverpath` does not contains any url or assets path for `book` object, that's why it's raise an error.

Comment: Thnx,,i solved it.    <%= image_tag(book.coverpath)if book.coverpath.present? %>

Comment: I have reverted your last edit, as it undid a good number of improvements. If you need to edit again, please refresh your browser first (to ensure you have the latest version) and then [check the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38716617/revisions) to ensure you are not making destructive changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always we need to handle nil data. In this case we need to check that image's coverpath is present or not. Below code snippet resolved my issue.

**<%= image_tag(book.coverpath) if book.coverpath.present? %>**

Comment: Thanks for adding this. We encourage posters to click the tick mark to the left of their working solution, to mark it as answered.